# Camunda tables not getting created on startup when I use Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, camunda

I start my project with spring boot and camunda and MySQL , but camunda tables cant create .
my config is :

```
spring:
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/austira
      username: root
      password: root
   jpa:
     database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
     database: MYSQL
     hibernate:
       ddl-auto: update
server:
  port: 9090

camunda:
  bpm:
    database:
      type: mysql
```

then I face with this exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'austira.act_ge_property' doesn't exist
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the database *austira* after starting the database?
Does the user have access to it?
Have the tables not been created during startup or is it only failing later, after the tables have been created and the engine tries to use them (see / provide more startup logs)?

Here is a working setup against MySQL (on Docker):
https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-mysql

(I changed the db name to camdb instead of austira)